# Dropbox API logout url is not working properly

Tags: php, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am using php sdk provided by dropbox to import images from user's account after the authorization.
All is working perfectly.
But the logout url (Which I have created) is not working properly.

Below is my code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href='https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<style>
    .loader {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url('Images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
    }
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
<script>
    function loader(){
        $('#load').show();
    }
    function loadExistingImages(){
        window.opener.$('#loader_img').show();
        result=null;
        window.opener.$('#fileupload').each(function () {
                var that = this;
                $.getJSON(this.action, function (result) {              
                    if (result && result.length) {
                        window.opener.$(that).fileupload('option', 'done')
                            .call(that, null, {result: result});
                //console.log('ss='+$('.table-striped tbody').find('.btn-danger').length);
                if(window.opener.$('.table-striped tbody').find('.btn-danger').length>0){
                    window.opener.$('.coo-images-other-buttons').show();
                }else{
                    window.opener.$('.coo-images-other-buttons').hide();  
                }   
                    }
                    window.opener.$('#loader_img').hide();

            if (window.opener.$('.table-striped tbody tr').length > 0)
            {
                window.opener.$('.table_tagline').show();
            }
                });
            });             
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#load').hide();</script>

<?php
/***********************************************************************
 * Plugin Name: Dropbox Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://www.picpixa.com/
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Ashish Shah
 * Description: Plugin To Import Images From User's Dropbox Account
 **********************************************************************/

session_start();
include_once '/home/picpixa/wp-config.php';
//ini_set("display_errors",0);
if(isset($_POST['copy']) && $_POST['dropbox'])
{
    $imgArray = $_POST['dropbox'];

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if(isset($current_user->ID) && trim($current_user->ID)!='' && trim($current_user->ID)!=0){
        $extraSessionStr = 'usr-'.md5($current_user->ID).'/';
        $user = $current_user->ID;
    }else{
        $sesstionId = session_id();
        $user = $sesstionId;
        $extraSessionStr = $sesstionId.'/';
    }

    foreach ($imgArray as $img)
    {
        $fileName=basename($img);
        // Read file content
        $file_content = file_get_contents($img);
        file_put_contents('/home/picpixa/server/php/files/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName, $file_content);
        //file_put_contents('/home/picpixa/server/php/thumbnails/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName, $file_content);

        //Get the image size
        $imgsize=get_headers($img,1);
        $imgsize = number_format(($imgsize["Content-Length"]/1024),2);

        /* To create thumbnail */

        // Max vert or horiz resolution
        $maxsize=80;

        // create new Imagick object
        $image = new Imagick($img); //"input_image_filename_and_location"

        // Resizes to whichever is larger, width or height
        if($image->getImageHeight() <= $image->getImageWidth())
        {
            // Resize image using the lanczos resampling algorithm based on width
            $image->resizeImage($maxsize,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
        }
        else
        {
            // Resize image using the lanczos resampling algorithm based on height
            $image->resizeImage(0,$maxsize,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
        }

        // Set to use jpeg compression
        $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        // Set compression level (1 lowest quality, 100 highest quality)
        $image->setImageCompressionQuality(75);
        // Strip out unneeded meta data
        $image->stripImage();
        // Writes resultant image to output directory
        $image->writeImage('/home/picpixa/server/php/thumbnails/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName); //"output_image_filename_and_location"
        // Destroys Imagick object, freeing allocated resources in the process
        $image->destroy();
    }
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //window.opener.$("#fileupload").append(div);
            window.opener.$('tbody.files').find('tr').remove();
            loadExistingImages();
        </script>
    <?php
        echo "<h2>The selected images have been moved.<br></h2>";
        echo "<h3>Please click on \"Proceed With Uploaded Images\" button to Proceed OR ";
        echo "Click on the \"Upload More Images\" Button to upload more images.</h3>";
    ?>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type='button' name='continue' value='Upload More Images' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='loader();window.location.href="";'>
            <input type='button' name='closeWindow' value='Proceed With Uploaded Images' class='btn btn-primary' onClick="window.close();">
        </div>
        <?php
            die();          
        }
        elseif (isset($_POST['copy']))
        {
            echo "<h2>You have not selected any image(s) to move.</h2><br><br>";
            echo "<h3>Please click on \"Close\" button to Close the window OR ";
            echo "Click on the \"Upload Images\" Button to upload images.</h3>";
        ?>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type='button' name='continue' value='Upload Images' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='loader();window.location.href="";'>
                <input type='button' name='closeWindow' value='Close' class='btn btn-primary' onClick="window.close();">
            </div>
        <?php
            die();
        }

require_once __DIR__.'/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/strict.php';

$appInfoFile = __DIR__."/AppInfo.json";

// NOTE: You should be using Composer's global autoloader. But just so these examples
// work for people who don't have Composer, we'll use the library's "autoload.php".
require_once __DIR__.'/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php';

use \Dropbox as dbx;
$requestPath = init();

if ($requestPath === "/") {
    $dbxClient = getClient();

    if ($dbxClient === false) {
        header("Location: ".getPath("dropbox-auth-start"));
        exit;
    }

    $path = "/";
    if (isset($_GET['path'])) $path = $_GET['path'];

    $entry = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren($path);
    if ($entry['is_dir']) {
        echo renderFolder($entry);
    }
    else {
        echo renderFile($entry);
    }
}
else if ($requestPath == "/download") {
    $dbxClient = getClient();

    if ($dbxClient === false) {
        header("Location: ".getPath("dropbox-auth-start"));
        exit;
    }

    if (!isset($_GET['path'])) {
        header("Location: ".getPath(""));
        exit;
    }
    $path = $_GET['path'];

    $fd = tmpfile();
    $metadata = $dbxClient->getFile($path, $fd);

    header("Content-Type: $metadata[mime_type]");
    fseek($fd, 0);
    fpassthru($fd);
    fclose($fd);
}
else if ($requestPath === "/upload") {
    if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        echo renderHtmlPage("Error", "Please choose a file to upload");
        exit;
    }

    if (!empty($_FILES['file']['error'])) {
        echo renderHtmlPage("Error", "Error ".$_FILES['file']['error']." uploading file. See <a href='http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php'>the docs</a> for details");
        exit;
    }

    $dbxClient = getClient();

    $remoteDir = "/";
    if (isset($_POST['folder'])) $remoteDir = $_POST['folder'];

    $remotePath = rtrim($remoteDir, "/")."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];

    $fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");
    $result = $dbxClient->uploadFile($remotePath, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $fp);
    fclose($fp);
    $str = print_r($result, TRUE);
    echo renderHtmlPage("Uploading File", "Result: <pre>$str</pre>");
}
else if ($requestPath === "/dropbox-auth-start") {
    $authorizeUrl = getWebAuth()->start();
    header("Location: $authorizeUrl");
}
else if ($requestPath === "/dropbox-auth-finish") {
    try {
        list($accessToken, $userId, $urlState) = getWebAuth()->finish($_GET);
        // We didn't pass in $urlState to finish, and we're assuming the session can't be
        // tampered with, so this should be null.
        assert($urlState === null);
    }
    catch (dbx\WebAuthException_BadRequest $ex) {
        respondWithError(400, "Bad Request");
        // Write full details to server error log.
        // IMPORTANT: Never show the $ex->getMessage() string to the user -- it could contain
        // sensitive information.
        error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: bad request: " . $ex->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
    catch (dbx\WebAuthException_BadState $ex) {
        // Auth session expired. Restart the auth process.
        header("Location: ".getPath("dropbox-auth-start"));
        exit;
    }
    catch (dbx\WebAuthException_Csrf $ex) {
        respondWithError(403, "Unauthorized", "CSRF mismatch");
        // Write full details to server error log.
        // IMPORTANT: Never show the $ex->getMessage() string to the user -- it contains
        // sensitive information that could be used to bypass the CSRF check.
        error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: CSRF mismatch: " . $ex->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
    catch (dbx\WebAuthException_NotApproved $ex) {
        echo renderHtmlPage("Not Authorized?", "Why not?");
        exit;
    }
    catch (dbx\WebAuthException_Provider $ex) {
        error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: unknown error: " . $ex->getMessage());
        respondWithError(500, "Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }
    catch (dbx\Exception $ex) {
        error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: error communicating with Dropbox API: " . $ex->getMessage());
        respondWithError(500, "Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }

    // NOTE: A real web app would store the access token in a database.
    $_SESSION['access-token'] = $accessToken;

    echo renderHtmlPage("Authorized!",
        "Authorization complete, <a href='".htmlspecialchars(getPath(""))."' onclick='loader()'>click here</a> to browse.");
}
else if ($requestPath === "/dropbox-auth-unlink") {
    // "Forget" the access token.
    unset($_SESSION['access-token']);
    //$_SESSION = array();

    echo renderHtmlPage("Logged Out",
        "<div class='modal-footer'>
            You have been logged out.<br>To Login Again click \"Login To Dropbox\"
            OR Click on the \"Proceed With Uploaded Images\" Button to upload more images.<br>
            <input type='button' name='login' value='Login To Dropbox' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='location.href = \"https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/index.php\";'>
            <input type='button' name='closeWindow' value='Close' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='window.close();'>
        </div>"
    );
}
else {
    echo renderHtmlPage("Bad URL", "No handler for $requestPath");
    exit;
}

function renderFolder($entry)
{
    /*echo "entry:<pre>";
    print_r($entry);
    echo "</pre>entry end.<br>Session:<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>Session end.";
    die;*/
    $dbxClient = getClient();//Using to use the createTemporaryDirectLink() function

    // TODO: Add a token to counter CSRF attacks.
   // $upload_path = htmlspecialchars(getPath('upload'));
    //$path = htmlspecialchars($entry['path']);
    //$form = <<<HTML <form action='$upload_path' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> <label for='file'>Upload file:</label> <input name='file' type='file'/> <input type='submit' value='Upload'/> <input name='folder' type='hidden' value='$path'/> </form> HTML;
    //$form =   <<<HTML HTML;
    $listing = "<div id='load' class='loader'></div>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>";
                if(isset($entry['contents']) && $entry['contents']){
                    $listing .= "<div class='modal-footer'>
                        <script>
                            function goDirect(){
                                alert(window.location);
                                window.location.href='dropbox-auth-unlink';
                            }
                        </script>
                        <input type='button' name='logout' value='Logout' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='goDirect()'>
                    </div>";
                }
                $listing .= "<form method='POST' action=''>
                    <div class='modal-body'>";
                        $i=0;
                        $showBtn=False;
                        foreach($entry['contents'] as $child) {
                            $type='Folder';
                            $cp = $child['path'];
                            $cn = basename($cp);
                            if (!$child['is_dir']){
                                $type=$child['mime_type'];
                            }
                            $cp = htmlspecialchars($cp);
                            $link = getPath("?path=".htmlspecialchars($cp));
                            if ($child['is_dir']){
                                $listing .= "<div class='baby_img'>Folder: <a style='text-decoration: none' href='$link'>$cn</a></div>";
                                $cn .= '/';
                            }
                            else{
                                if(strcmp($type,'image/*')==1){
                                    $img = $dbxClient->createTemporaryDirectLink($cp);
                                    $listing .= "<div class='baby_img'>
                                        <input type='checkbox' id='dropbox_".$i."' name='dropbox[]'  value='".$img[0]."' class='styled' />";
                                        $listing .= "<img src='".$img[0]."' height = '100px' width = '100px' class='img-responsive'/>";
                                    $listing .= '</div>';
                                    $i++;
                                    $showBtn=true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    $listing .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">';
                        if($showBtn){
                            $listing .= "<input type='submit' name='copy' value='Copy Selected Files' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='loader()'>";
                        }
                        $listing .= "<input type='button' name='closeWindow' value='Close This Window' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='window.close();'>";
                    $listing .= '</div>';
                $listing .= "</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
    return renderHtmlPage("App/picpixa$entry[path]", $listing);
}

function getAppConfig()
{
    global $appInfoFile;

    try {
        $appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile($appInfoFile);
    }
    catch (dbx\AppInfoLoadException $ex) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to load \"$appInfoFile\": " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $clientIdentifier = "examples-web-file-browser";
    $userLocale = null;

    return array($appInfo, $clientIdentifier, $userLocale);
}

function getClient()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['access-token'])) {
        return false;
    }

    list($appInfo, $clientIdentifier, $userLocale) = getAppConfig();
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['access-token'];
    return new dbx\Client($accessToken, $clientIdentifier, $userLocale, $appInfo->getHost());
}

function getWebAuth()
{
    list($appInfo, $clientIdentifier, $userLocale) = getAppConfig();
    $redirectUri = getUrl("dropbox-auth-finish");
    $csrfTokenStore = new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
    return new dbx\WebAuth($appInfo, $clientIdentifier, $redirectUri, $csrfTokenStore, $userLocale);
}

function renderFile($entry)
{
    $metadataStr = htmlspecialchars(print_r($entry, true));
    $downloadPath = getPath("download?path=".htmlspecialchars($entry['path']));
    $body = <<<HTML
<pre>$metadataStr</pre>
<a href="$downloadPath">Download this file</a>
HTML;

    return renderHtmlPage("File: ".$entry['path'], $body);
}

function renderHtmlPage($title, $body)
{
    return <<<HTML
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
                <title>$title</title>

                <!-- Bootstrap -->
                <link href='https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>
                <link href='https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
            </head>
            <body>
                $body
            </body>
        </html>
HTML;
}

function respondWithError($code, $title, $body = "")
{
    $proto = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
    header("$proto $code $title", true, $code);
    echo renderHtmlPage($title, $body);
}

function getUrl($relative_path)
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') {
        $scheme = "https";
    } else {
        $scheme = "http";
    }
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $path = getPath($relative_path);
    return $scheme."://".$host.$path;
}

function getPath($relative_path)
{
    if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server') {
        return "/".$relative_path;
    } else {
        return $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."/".$relative_path;
    }
}

function init()
{
    global $argv;

    // If we were run as a command-line script, launch the PHP built-in web server.
    if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
        launchBuiltInWebServer($argv);
        assert(false);
    }

    if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server') {
        // For when we're running under PHP's built-in web server, do the routing here.
        return $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    }
    else {
        // For when we're running under CGI or mod_php.
        if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
            return $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
        } else {
            return "/";
        }
    }
}

function launchBuiltInWebServer($argv)
{
    // The built-in web server is only available in PHP 5.4+.
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
        fprintf(STDERR,
            "Unable to run example. The version of PHP you used to run this script (".PHP_VERSION.")<br>".
            "doesn't have a built-in web server. You need PHP 5.4 or newer.<br>".
            "<br>".
            "You can still run this example if you have a web server that supports PHP 5.3.<br>".
            "Copy the Dropbox PHP SDK into your web server's document path and access it there.<br>");
        exit(2);
    }

    $php_file = $argv[0];
    if (count($argv) === 1) {
        $port = 5000;
    } else if (count($argv) === 2) {
        $port = intval($argv[1]);
    } else {
        fprintf(STDERR,
            "Too many arguments.<br>".
            "Usage: php $argv[0] [server-port]<br>");
        exit(1);
    }

    $host = "localhost:$port";
    $cmd = escapeshellarg(PHP_BINARY)." -S ".$host." ".escapeshellarg($php_file);
    $descriptors = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"), // Process' stdin. We'll just close this right away.
        1 => STDOUT, // Relay process' stdout to ours.
        2 => STDERR, // Relay process' stderr to ours.
    );
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);
    if ($proc === false) {
        fprintf(STDERR,
            "Unable to launch PHP's built-in web server. Used command:<br>".
            " $cmd<br>");
        exit(2);
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]); // Close the process' stdin.
    $exitCode = proc_close($proc); // Wait for process to exit.
    exit($exitCode);
}
?>
```

Can anyone please help me?

**My Observation:**
when the url in the address bar is "/index.php/" , then the logout button is working fine.
But when the url in the address bar is "/index.php" , then the logout button is not working.

I tried to give if condition in the script but failed.
Please help me out.

Comment: In what way does it fail? Do you get an error? What's the URL of the page you land on?

Comment: My URL is www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/index.php from which I send the request
Then when I click on Logout it lands on www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/dropbox-auth-unlink
and gives an error page not found
But when the Original URL is www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/index.php/ (Observe "/") it is working fine

Comment: @Greg so as a temporiry solution I have changed the original url to www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-dropbox/index.php/
But i need the perfect solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code:

```
function goDirect(){
    alert(window.location);
    window.location.href='dropbox-auth-unlink';
}
```

Setting `window.location.href` to a relative path will replace the last segment of the URL. So if the URL is `.../plugin-dropbox/index.php`, you'll end up browsing to `.../plugin-dropbox/dropbox-auth-unlink`. If, on the other hand, you have `.../plugin-dropbox/index.php/` (note the extra, empty, segment at the end of the URL), you'll end up browsing to `.../plugin-dropbox/index.php/dropbox-auth-unlink`.

Apparently the latter is the URL you want. So you could drop the trailing slash (just use `index.php`) and try one of these:

```
function goDirect() {
    // Simple but doesn't work well with query string parameters:
    // window.location.href += '/dropbox-auth-unlink';

    // An alternative that requires hardcoding the 'index.php' part:
    window.location.href = 'index.php/dropbox-auth-unlink';
}
```

Comment: Thanx smarx,
But there is one more problem.
It does not tottaly log user out.
I mean while clicking on Login, it does not ask for user name and password. It gives output like: "Auth Complete, Click here to browse" (Which shall be coming after the login...

Comment: The user will only have to enter their username and password if they're not currently logged in to `dropbox.com`. And they'll only have to click "allow" to allow access to your app if they haven't done so previously. So this is the expected behavior.

Comment: have one doubt... if user is logged out of dropbox then the api will ask for the user name and pass. Correct.
But after login through api... then logout... then login again... then it is not asking to login again as I told you previously...
Shall not user log out of dropbox if he is logged in through api?
Just a doubt...

Comment: "then login again... then it is not asking to login again" Why would the user have to log in again if they just did?

Comment: yes smarx but my concern is that when they logout from my api they may not know that they are still logged in dropbox site...
and some one may access that account...

Comment: Hello Smarx,
I am giving you a CASE.
1. I open my API and log in to dropbox.
2. In the new tab, I open dropbox.com it is already logged in. (Correct)
3. Now I log out from dropbox.com
4. I again open my API, It is not asking me for authentication. Though I have logged out from dropbox.com. Is this scenario correct?

Comment: @AshishShah Well, I guess that's up to you. If your app remembers the user (as most good apps do), then yes, the user will still be logged in to your app. If you choose not to, you can forget the user each time, in which case they'll have to log in.

Comment: I dont want my app to forget user. I just wish that my app should check weather the user is logged in to dropbox.com or not. If user is not logged in to dropbox.com then s/he has to login to my app also even if s/he has alreafy logged in to my app.